# How to make Color gradient-weigthed distance image in opencv (python)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

How to make Color gradient-weigthed distance in OpenCV for Python? For all my research that I am doing I am find just gradient distance without the color information, please can anyone know the path to it? Many thanks in advance

[image: Example of Color gradient-weigthed distance]

[Image source](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/252046604_Automatic_segmentation_of_clustered_breast_cancer_cells_using_watershed_and_concave_vertex_graph).

***The objective is not doing Distance transformation alone, but doing it with color information (in grayscale)**

Comment: I have never heard of that term, which means it is not a standard tool. I suggest reading that paper to see if they explain it there.

Comment: how lord you scare me now, and this technic is the best for what I need

Comment: That technique to separate cells is typically applied with a normal distance transform. You should then also apply a small h-transform before the watershed, it removes redundant local minima, avoiding the oversegmentation that you see in the linked figure.

Comment: To me it looks like they binarized (a), applied a distance transformation and then inverted the image. This should yield you exactly (c).

Comment: dear @CrisLuengo and @T A, In fact, it's similar the difference is it uses distance transformation with color information, not just black and white,
This is the crucial part color+ distance transformation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution based on these papers:

> https://www.researchgate.net/publication/257690553_Automatic_image_segmentation_of_nuclear_stained_breast_tissue_sections_using_color_active_contour_model_and_an_improved_watershed_method
>   https://www.researchgate.net/publication/260755668_A_color_and_shape_based_algorithm_for_segmentation_of_white_blood_cells_in_peripheral_blood_and_bone_marrow_images

Was just the merge of the two techniques, thank you all.

[image]
[image]

[image]